# React react-switch Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component

Tags: reactjs, datatable

I am trying to write React Component with DataTable and react-switch.

It seems it working, but when I see the developer console, there is error:

Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.

The error shows only when I "drag" the Switch. If I only click on the switch, there is no error.

```
import React from 'react';
import { authenticationService } from '../../helpers/AuthenticationService';
import axios from 'axios';
import DataTable from 'react-data-table-component';
import Switch from "react-switch";


class ProductEshop extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            isCancelled: false,
            data: [],
            checked: false
        }
    }


    handleButtonClick = (state, row) => {

    this.setState({
            data: this.state.data.map((item, index) =>
                item.eshopId == row.eshopId ? { ...item, isActive: !item.isActive } : item,
            )
     })
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        const currentUser = authenticationService.currentUserValue;

        axios.get('/api/product/' + this.props.id + '/eshops', { headers: { "Authorization": `Bearer ${currentUser.token}` } }).then(res => {
            this.setState({ data: res.data });
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }

    render() {
        const columns = (clickHandler => [

            {
                cell: (row) => <Switch onChange={(e) => clickHandler(e, row)} checked={row.isActive} />
            },
            {
                name: 'Název',
                selector: 'name',
                sortable: true,
            }
        ]);

        return (<div>
            <DataTable
                title="Products"
                data={this.state.data}
                columns={columns(this.handleButtonClick)}
                onRowSelected={this.handleChange}
                paginationComponentOptions={this.state.paggination}
                pagination
                dense
            />
        </div>)
    }
}

export default (ProductEshop)
```

Can somebody help please?

UPDATE: the error is created in handleButtonClick

Answer (score 0):

It happens because this.setState is called in an async process. This means even if you unmount the component Axios will try to execute `then` and that's why you get the warning. You need to cancel the request on `componentWillUnmount`

```
  componentDidMount () {
    this.axiosCancelSource = axios.CancelToken.source()

   axios.get('/api/product/' + this.props.id + '/eshops', 
  { headers: { "Authorization": `Bearer ${currentUser.token}` }, 
    cancelToken: this.axiosCancelSource.token })
   .then(res => {
            this.setState({ data: res.data });
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
      });
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    this.axiosCancelSource.cancel('Axios request canceled.')
  }
```

Comment: thanks, but the message still shows. I dont think that the problem is Axios, because the error is created in handleButtonClick.